# Javascript Virtual Pet logic

Tags: javascript, html, virtual

I'm 90% done with my virtual pet game I just need help with two things. A) I'm trying to create logic for when I type in "walk" but I have zero energy it displays an error saying "not enough energy for a walk" and does not affect the happiness or energy variables. B) I'm trying to create a console log that incorporates strings and variables. It currently will tell me the energy and happiness levels but displays the pets name as "NaN". Here is my code so far:

```
const Pet = prompt ("Name your pet");
document.write(Action);
let Energy = 0;
let Happiness = 0;
document.write(Energy);
document.write(Happiness);
for (i=0; i<6; i++){
var Action = prompt ("feed, pet, or walk?");
   if (Action === "feed") {
Energy = (Energy + 2);
   } else if (Action === "pet") {
Happiness = (Happiness + 1);
   } else if (Action === "walk")
{
Happiness = ( Happiness + 2); 
Energy = (Energy - 1);
   } 
   
   

}; 
console.log (Pet)
console.log (Happiness)
console.log (Energy)
console.log(+ Pet + " has " + Happiness + " happiness and " + Energy + " energy");
```

Comment: `console.log(+ Pet + " has " + Happiness + " happiness and " + Energy + " energy"); ` The name is not displaying because you have a `+` sign at the beginning of the log, remove that and it should display name. You are also calling the document.write operation for Action before you create it.

Comment: why do you have a `+` sign at the beginning of bracket